# Repeated Riemann-Stieltjes integration.

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

- Suppose $\alpha$, $\beta$ are increasing functions on $[a, b]$ such that $\alpha \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$, and $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha) \cap \mathscr{R}(\beta)$. Show that $\int_{a}^{x} f(t) d \alpha(t)$, regarded as a function of $x$, belongs to $\mathscr{R}(\beta)$, and that
  \begin{equation*}
      \int_{t=a}^{b}\bigg(\int_{s=a}^{t} f(s) d \alpha(s)\bigg) d \beta(t) = \int_{t=a}^{b}(\beta(b) - \beta(t)) f(t) d \alpha(t)
  \end{equation*}
- Show that given continuous functions $u$ and $v$ on $[a, b]$, there exists a continuous function $w$ of two variables such that for any $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$, one has
  \begin{equation*}
      \int_{t=a}^{x} u(t)\bigg(\int_{s=a}^{t} v(s) f(s) d s\bigg) d t =  \int_{t=a}^{x} w(x, t) f(t) d t
  \end{equation*}

It has a clue for the 1st bullet, which is as follows,

First consider the case where $f$ is everywhere $ \geq 0$, since in this case, one can easily describe the least and greatest values of $\int_{s=a}^t f(s) d \alpha(s)$ on any interval as the values at the respective ends of the interval; then get the general case by writing any $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha) \cap \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ as a difference of two nonnegative-valued functions in $\mathscr{R}(\alpha) \cap \mathscr{R}(\beta)$.

For the 1st bullet, I know the result holds when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differentiable, but I have no idea how to prove it for the general case. Also, I have no clue about the 2nd bullet. This exercise is raised based on baby Rudin's first 6 chapters, so please do not resort to any advanced methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t) \, d\alpha(t)$.  Following the hint and starting with the case where $f$ is nonnegative, we can show that $F$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\beta$ by showing that Riemann's condition holds.  That is, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that the difference between upper and lower sums of $F$ with respect to $\beta$ satisifes $U(P,F,\beta) - L(P,F,\beta) < \epsilon$.

For the partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n=b$ we have (for $f \geqslant 0$)

$$\tag{1}U(P,F,\beta) - L(P,F,\beta)= \sum_{j=1}^n[\sup_{x\in [x_{j-1},x_j]}F(x)-\inf_{x\in [x_{j-1},x_j]}F(x)]\,[\beta(x_j)- \beta(x_{j-1})]\\= \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}f(t) \, d\alpha(t)\,[\beta(x_j)- \beta(x_{j-1})]$$

SInce $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable it is bounded and there exists $M_f > 0$ such that $0 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M_f$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and

$$\tag{2}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}f(t) \, d\alpha(t)\leqslant M_f [ \alpha(x_{j}) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]$$

Together (1) and (2) imply

$$\tag{3}U(P,F,\beta) - L(P,F,\beta)\leqslant M_f \sum_{j=1}^n[ \alpha(x_{j}) - \alpha(x_{j-1})][ \beta(x_{j}) - \beta(x_{j-1})]$$

We can proceed in either of two ways to show that there exists a partition $P$ such that the sum on the RHS of (3) is less than $\epsilon/ M_f$. One way is to notice that the sum is the difference between  the upper and lower sums of $\alpha$ with respect to $\beta$ and, since $\alpha \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$, the difference can be made as small as desired with an appropriately fine partition. The other way is to use the fact that when $\alpha$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\beta$, then both functions cannot be discontinuous from the right or left together. Therefore, there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(P,F,\beta) - L(P,F,\beta) < \epsilon$ and $F \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$.

Leaving the remaining details of the proof for the general case to you, we can complete the first part by noting that

$$\int_a^b \left(\int_a^t f(s) \, d\alpha(s)\right) \, d\beta(t)= \int_a^b \left(\int_a^b f(s) \mathbf{1}_{s \leqslant t}(s,t) \, d\alpha(s)\right) \, d\beta(t),$$

where the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{s \leqslant t}(s,t) = 1$ if $s \leqslant t$ and $0$, otherwise. Applying Fubini's theorem it follows that

$$\int_a^b \left(\int_a^t f(s) \, d\alpha(s)\right) \, d\beta(t)=\int_a^b f(s)\left(\int_a^b  \mathbf{1}_{s \leqslant t}(s,t) \, d\beta(t)\right) \, d\alpha(s)\\ = \int_a^b f(s)\left(\int_s^b   \, d\beta(t)\right)\, d\alpha(s) = \int_a^b [\beta(b) - \beta(s)]f(s) \, d\alpha(s)$$

---

Another approach is an application of integration by parts. For Riemann-Stieltjes integrals this guarantees the implications $\alpha \in \mathscr{R}(\beta) \implies \beta \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$  and $ \beta \in \mathscr{R}(F) \implies F \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$.

It is not difficult  to show using Riemann-Stieltjes sums that

$$\int_a^b \beta(t) \, dF(t) = \int_a^b \beta(t)f(t) \, d\alpha(t),$$

and then with further application of IBP, we get

$$\int_a^b F(t) \, d\beta(t) = F(b)\beta(b) - \underbrace{F(a)\beta(a)}_{= \,0} - \int_a^b \beta(t)f(t) \, d\alpha(t)\\= \int_a^b [\beta(b) - \beta(t)]f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Because this homework is the supplement of baby Rudin, the Fubini's theorem is pretended not to be learnt currently; Also, the integration by parts for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals has the same situation. Anyway, may I ask where the suggestion that f is nonnegetive is used? It seems that the one who cooked this problem has other "fundamental" way to prove it

Comment: @hmeng:  I'm using $f \geqslant 0$ to get (1), because we have that $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$ is increasing. Whence $\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}F(x) = \int_a^{x_j}f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$ and $\inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}F(x) = \int_a^{x_{j-1}}f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$.

Comment: That is what they are suggesting you show with "...one can easily describe the least and greatest values of $\int_{s=a}^t f(s) d \alpha(s)$ on any interval as the values at the respective ends of the interval".  So I don't think there is some other way in mind.

Comment: Integration by parts is a very elementary property of the RS-integral following almost immediately from the definition in terms of Riemann-Stieltjes sums.

Comment: Oh, I thought the nonnegative f would be used in proving the equality in the 1st bullet, since for the 1st part of the 1st bullet, once F(x) is continuous, we can directly reach the conclusion that F is R(beta).